# redirecting output of two commands

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm wondering if there's a one-liner to do the following on Windows:

```
myCommand options1 | cut -c 10-20 > temp1.txt
myCommand options2 | cut -c 10-20 > temp2.txt
paste temp1.txt temp2.txt
```

I'd also like to do similar using `diff` instead of `paste` but I'm guessing the answer would be the same (yes?).  In general temp1 and 2 will both have more than one line of text.  I found the following which looks like a similar question 
[Print output of two commands in two columns in excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379912/print-output-of-two-commands-in-two-columns-in-excel-file)
but that doesn't have an answer.

Edit/Update: I realize now that I wasn't very clear about the 'one-liner'.  Obviously I can put all three lines together on one line by simply separating them with ampersands.  That's not what I'm looking for.  I vaguely recall from using Unix many years ago that backticks could be used for things like this.  Maybe something like

```
paste `cmd1` `cmd2`
```

not really too sure(?).  That's the sort of thing I'm looking for (on windows). Ideally it would not involve (much) more typing than simply entering the three lines above.  Does this exist?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: OS is Windows 7.  The paste, diff, and cut are GNU stuff for win32 (probably found them here years ago I think? - they're sooo great!!!)

Comment: Don't know much about Windows or if the new Win10 `bash` can be installed on Win7, but if/when Windows gets clever, you may be able to do `paste <(myCommand ... 10-20) <(myCommand ... 10-20)`.

Comment: Yes, Mark!  That's very much what I'm looking for (see edit/clarification above).  Your suggestion resembles what I want but upon execution I get "The system cannot find the file specified"  Is there a different syntax that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll never understand why one wants to use one-liners, but here you go:

```
(ping localhost |find "Mini" & ipconfig |find "IPv4")>temp.txt
```

**edit** to show output of both commands side by side:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ping localhost |find "TTL" >1.txt
ipconfig |find ":" >2.txt

<1.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (2.txt) do (
    set /p "x="
    echo !x! ; %%a
    set "x=-"
  )
)>temp1.txt
```

same as one-liner (as batchfile):

```
cmd /v:on /c ping localhost |find "TTL" >1.txt & ipconfig |find ":" >2.txt & <1.txt (for /f "delims=" %%a in (2.txt) do (set /p "x=" & echo !x! ; %%a &  set "x=-"))>temp2.txt
```

one-liner to be used on command line:

```
cmd /v:on /c "ping localhost |find "TTL" >1.txt & ipconfig |find ":" >2.txt & <1.txt (for /f "delims=" %a in (2.txt) do @(set /p "x=" & echo !x! ; %a &  set "x=-"))>temp.txt"
```

Note: in the result there are as much lines as in `2.txt` (output of the second command). If `1.txt` has more lines, they are omitted (less lines are not a problem)

Comment: Hmmm. If you'd like to understand "why", perhaps you should phrase it as a question rather than simply lament a perception of yours (perhaps indefinetly?).  Regarding the 'beginners', I'm not sure if that's intended to be insulting but I will say I am of an age that I very well may have been computing longer than you.  Either way, it seems inappropriate to me and your suggestion is not helpful.  This just pipes the output of one command to the next, and then to the next, finally putting the output of the last command in temp.txt.

Comment: OK, sorry, didn't see the ampersand.  Still though, it just "stacks" the output.  I'd like the first row of each command to be on the first line, the second line of each on the second, ... so on.

Comment: That would require to run both commands synchronized, that's not possible. You have to cache both outputs (into files?) and then use a script to merge the two files - but that's definitively no oneliner. (btw: no offense intended; I just noticed, that especially "low-reps" tend to request one-liners - and hey, we are talking about scripts; keep them readable, no reason for code-golfing). You should add an example to your question  (input, desired output) to make clear, what you expect.

Comment: I retract from "definitively no onliner" `:)` See my edit.

Comment: That's a very clever way to avoid using paste!  Fortunately I do have paste on my system (and stand back, I'm not afraid to use it!)  Unfortunately that also doesn't help for using diff on the same example.  Please see edit/clarification above as I realize I wasn't very clear about what I'm looking for.

Comment: if you tag it `Windows`, `batch-file`, `cmd`, expect batch solutions. You might want to add the `bash` tag to attract Unix-people.

Comment: Thanks.  That was silly of me. Tag removed.  I didn't add bash as I'm really looking for a windows/dos solution.  As I think about it more, you might consider posting your solution to the other link I referenced as they might not have paste on their system and could find it useful.  Again, it seems to be a rather clever substitute (could need maybe a tweak though - didn't try it).

Comment: Well Stephan.  I suppose you "win" for the best answer by default (it's the only one!).  It appears to be not your actual answer (your batchfile solution) because that's really just a workaround/alternate for paste.  I'm referring to the "that's not possible" part.  It would be nice (i.e., cleaner) if someone actually gave that answer definitively - (strictly speaking you mention this but then give a solution so I interpret that's not really your answer - it's the batchfile solution you offer - so I didn't mark this as an answer).  Many thanks for your help!  Anyone else can chime in?

Comment: running two commands parallel or even synchronized is not possible (at least in batch). That's why I used temporary textfiles as a workaround, which *can*  be read in parallel (with that ugly hack ( `paste` isn't a batch command and I don't have it)). Agreed, that is more a workaround than a clean solution. Good luck, finding an acceptable solution (my suggestion still stands: add the `bash` tag - *nix people should know better about `paste` or alternatives)